# understanding $\theta,\Theta, d\theta, \mu(d\theta)$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, iterated-function-system

Let $(\mathcal S, d)$ be a metric space. let $\{f_\theta: \theta \in \Theta\} $ be a family of Lipschitz functions on $\mathcal S$ and $\mu$ be a probability distribution on $\Theta$. Suppose that $\int K_{\theta}\mu(d\theta)<\infty, \int d(f_{\theta}(x_0), x_0)\mu (d\theta)<\infty$ for some $x_0\in S$, and $\int \log K_{\theta}\mu(d\theta)<\infty $
Then the induced Markov chain has a unique stationary distribution. 
This is from  here in page $47$, Theorem $1.1$ in the paper [Iterated Random Functions](https://statweb.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/iterate.pdf)

Now, I am not able to understand, $\theta,\Theta, d\theta, \mu(d\theta)$ here in this context. Could anyone help me to understand these four things by a little example maybe? That would so help, Thanks a lot.

For example, can I take $\Theta=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$? If yes, Then what will happen to the other three objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** you were to take $\Theta= \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ then $\theta$ would be any one of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.  That is, $\theta\in\Theta$ means that the variable $\theta$ can take on any of the values in the set $\Theta$.  Since $\Theta$ is **discrete**, not continuous, "$d\theta$" would not be defined.  If instead, we take $\Theta= (0, 1)$, the open interval from 0 to 1, then $\theta$ could be any number between 0 and 1 and $d\theta$ would be the usual differential from Calculus.  I believe that "$\mu d\theta$" is the "Lebesgue measure" defined by the variable $\theta$ though I would have expected the notation "$d\mu(\theta)$.

Comment: In your original post you said "Let $\{f_\theta |\theta\in\Theta\}$ be a family of Lipschitz functions on S".  That is, you have a set of functions "indexed" by $\theta$- for every value of $\theta$, there is a function, $f_\theta$, corresponding to that $\theta$.  That is the same as saying that we have a function of two variables, $f(x,\theta)$ and that $f_\theta$ is that function where $\theta$ is held fixed so that x is the only variable.  For example, if $f(x, \theta)= x\sin(\theta)+ x^2\cos(\theta)$ then $f_0= x^2$ and $f_{\pi/2}= x$.

Answer (score 1):

To complete the previous answer, if we go to the discrete case, I suppose it is implied that: 
$$\int K_\theta \mu(d\theta) = \sum_{\theta \in \Theta} K_\theta \mu(\theta)$$

It is therefore not necessary to suppose that the set $\Theta$ is continuous.

Also, I believe that $\mu(d\theta)$ is simply a way to write the probability measure as a distribution that you apply to a given small element $d\theta$, which can look more intuitive I guess?

And to give a small example, say $f_\theta$ is the function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f_\theta (x) = \theta \times x$, then $\theta$ can indeed be any number and therefore $\Theta$ can be any set.

Comment: So, $\int \log K_{\theta}\mu (d \theta)=\sum \log K_\theta\mu(\theta)$? the example you gave should be expressed as $f_{\theta}: \Theta\times \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, If you read the original paper at least first 2 page, what do you think the author has meant about $\theta$?

Comment: @miosaki, the author presents $\theta$ as what decides how a given Markov chain moves one step forward, so I guess it is a parameter which tells the chain "if you were in state X, then now you are in state Y" via a function $f_\theta$, i.e. $ Y = f_\theta (X)$